# Restart game without exit from application

Tags: c#

I made a simple adventure game, where player has to kill all enemies. The player has a health point, if this health point <= 0 game is over and then show menu of game (there is start buton, quit buton, restart buton). If game is over and if player choose restart i would like to the game start for the beginning. Actually I have something like that in Form with game

```
private void checkHitPoints(int playerHitPoints)
{
    if (game.PlayerHitPoints <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have been killed", "Opsss");
        menu.VisibleRestart();
        menu.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And in the Form with menu something like this

```
private void restartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Dungeons dungeons = new Dungeons();
        }
```

I try to call the constructor if I press the restartButton, but it doesn't work unfortunately. Moreover constructor of main class with game looks like this

```
public Dungeons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            player30.Visible = true;
            CenterToScreen();
            this.Show();
            menu.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Could you explain me where i made mistake?

Comment: How do you start the Game? i.e when you click the start button.

Comment: which ui framework are you using? WinForms, WPF, ...

Comment: Unfortunately I guess it's wrong, but the main window is gameboard, and in constructor and there is menu.ShowDialog(), when i press the start i made this.Close() and the i can play :/ If you want to you can see in Menu and Dungeons on GitHub, but i change these classes a bit. https://github.com/SimonWithYerba/Dungeons

Comment: @Ackdari WinForms. I don't know which framework, but VS 2017 downloaded in this year

Comment: Hi, While i understand the link to a GitHub, i will add that question must be selfcontaint with an [MCVE]. For the reproduction of your issue we do not need the definition of the game and can just assume it's a black screen without changing the question. Could you sumarize the architecture forgeting about menu and how the game work? Like programa lunch formA, formA has formB, formB button need to close formA/B and relunch it

Comment: Do you have a state to save? Information that need to persiste  on the restart? are they store somewhere? database? file? Define everything using minimal component few form 2 button. deine what need to be persist and from where.  You will have a mutch clearer path.

Comment: @xdtTransform I understand. Thank you for answer, I take into account your tips. Thank you once again.

Answer (score -1):

> where i made mistake?

It looks like u made one here:

```
this.Close();
Dungeons dungeons = new Dungeons();
```

Take a look at this code! You create `dungeons` variable and instantly dispose it as soon as `restartButton_Click` function ends. You'd better move `dungeons` variable out of the function scope like this:

```
Dungeons dungeons;
private void restartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dungeons = new Dungeons();
}
```

And `this.Close()` just closes your app (current form).

Answer (score -1):

Just call [Application.Restart()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.restart?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
    private void restartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }
```

Comment: I know this solution, but if I use it app restart, I care to "load" initial state

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution, not sure why the down vote.  The author gave no indication that he needed to "load" initial state, or that he was aware of this approach and didn't want to use it...